# Symfony 6.2 LDAP login

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I want to implement login in SF via LDAP.
I am following the instruction on the official Symfony website.
Unfortunately, I get the message /with good login details/:

**"Invalid credentials."**

My part of services.yaml:

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
        tags:
            - ldap
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            -   host: host
                port: 389
                encryption: false
                options:
                    protocol_version: 3
                    referrals: false
```

My part of security.yaml:

```
            form_login_ldap:
               service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
               dn_string: 'uid={user_identifier},dc=company,dc=com,dc=pl'
               default_target_path: app_dashboard
               login_path: app_login
               check_path: app_login
               query_string: null
               enable_csrf: true
```

Comment for this part:
I didn't use this:
your text
`dn_string: 'DOMAIN\{username}'`
I used the one as you can see, it's from the official Symfony documentation.

Please help.

I tried to follow the recommendations from Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some debug infos from your app log folder and use a tools like *ldapsearch* (from https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/LDAPUtils) to check your credentials BEFORE doing any test in Symfony ?

For example, with anonymous search (if the server authorise it) :

```
ldapsearch -x -d1 -H ldap://ldap.yourdomain.tld:389
```

It's a good tool to see your "ou,dc,cn,uid..." from the LDAP structure server.

Comment: The permissions are good, I used the ldapsearch command and as a result the server listed the users.
However, in Symfony I have a problem.
Depending on how I set the configuration:
1. If I give ldap as provider, it says: "Can't connect to LDAP server"
2. Without ldap provider, with standard, I have "Invalid credentials".

Comment: Searching users in LDAP server without credentials depend of its configuration.

Without any log from your app/ldap form, it will be difficult to help you and find where is the problem.

Have you try this code in a simple page (without any form) [https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html) ?

In my old project, I start with this example to debug step by step, and find the bug of certificate for LDAPS/SSL which need to be install on the web server...

Comment: Also some good documentation and example : [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php)